# How can I apply Tailwind CSS classes to SVG elements using D3.js (in VSCODE)?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, d3.js, tailwind-css

How can I apply Tailwind CSS classes to SVG elements using D3.js?

I'm working on a web project where I need to use both Tailwind CSS and D3.js. However, I'm having trouble applying Tailwind CSS classes to SVG elements using the .attr() method in D3.js.

For example, when I try to apply the `fill-red-500` class to a rectangle using `d3.select('rect').attr('class', 'fill-red-500')`, the class doesn't seem to be applied correctly, and the rectangle doesn't change color.

I have confirmed that my Tailwind configuration file is correct since I was able to use it successfully with `tooltip.html("<div class="bg-red-500">hello world</div>")`. However, I don't want to use `.html()` all the time because I am using D3.js to make coding charts easier.

I have also tried different approaches, but none of them seem to work. I have verified that the class is shown in devtools, but no styles appear on the screen.

My project uses Vite as the bundler, and I am writing vanilla JS with D3.js. I am using Tailwind CSS without any CSS applied to the entire project. The browser I am testing on is Chrome, and my operating system is Windows 11.

Is there a way to make Tailwind read the string inside the `.attr("class", "tailwindclass")` method in D3.js? I am open to any solution, even changing the configuration. Ideally, the solution should also work programmatically. For example, something like `() => { if(num>60) {return "fill-green-500"} return "fill-red-500" }` should work fine.

Please let me know if I need to provide any additional information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the same scenario happened also to me, here is a simple solution I found out:

#### TLDR:

To apply Tailwind CSS classes to SVG elements using *D3.js*,

you can use the `.classed()` method in *D3.js*

instead of the `.attr()` method.

---

## DETAILED ANSWER:

The `.classed()` method adds classes to the selected *D3.js* elements.

---

Somehow seems that the tailwind's terminal command read it fine,

in my case was:

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
```

using *Vite* as a bundler like you, and Normal Javascript (Vanilla).

---

as for my tailwindcss configuration, here it is:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

as you see, I made the `.content` object read also the javascript files present in the directory.
(using `"./*.{html,js}"` regex)

> but as I read from your question, the problem isn't there... I just pointed out to the future devs that read this, maybe can be helpful

---

Here is an example code snippet that demonstrates how to use `.classed()` method to apply a Tailwind CSS class to an SVG rectangle element:

```js
d3.select('svg')
  .append("rect")
  .classed('fill-red-500', true) // here the "class" working in tailwind
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("height", 50)
  .attr("width", 50)

console.clear() // just for the snippet, you don't need it
```

```html
<!-- don't use this script in production, this is only for stackoverflow snippet.... use npm instead -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.8.2/d3.min.js" integrity="sha512-oKI0pS1ut+mxQZdqnD3w9fqArLyILRsT3Dx0B+8RVEXzEk3aNK3J3pWlaGJ8MtTs1oiwyXDAH6hG6jy1sY0YqA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<svg height="300" width="300"></svg>
```

as you see in the snippet before, this method `.classed('fill-red-500', true)` needs two parameters:

1. a string with the name of the tailwind class (similar to the `.attr()` you already know well)
2. a boolean.

   - if you pass `true` then the class is applied to the svg element

     (for get you the idea: is like using the `.classList.add()` in vanilla JS)
   - if you pass `false` then the class isn't applied to the svg element

     (for get you the idea: is like using the `.classList.remove()` in vanilla JS)

---

##### Isn't Cool?

if you have some experience with d3js,

you definitely know that it is common to use `callback functions`,

like this `() => {}`.

---

and if you use the `.data(dataset).enter()` methods to the SVG elements (you should do it to gain the advantages of D3js),

then you can also use `(d) => {}`, so then you can do some calculations and return something

(in this case, can be `true` or `false`... if you return something else like a string or numbers, from what I know javascript tend to behave like is returned a `true` unless is an empty string `""` or `null` or `undefined`)

The `data()` method is used to attach the data to those elements. The `dataset` array is passed as an argument to the method.

---

Here is an example where you can also use a function to dynamically set the class based on some condition:

```js
  .classed('fill-green-500', (num) => num > 50) // if num is greater than 50 then add green
  .classed('fill-red-500', (num) => num <= 50); // if num is less or equal to 50 then add the class red.
```

---

## IDE Intellisense

*and what about the IntelliSense?*

it won't show the popup of suggestions by default.

---

and for this reason, I tried to open an issue on the tailwind GitHub page for you...

In the end everything is possible :)
, and I got a solution for you!

---

*and what it is?*

you need to change the tailwind configuration by following the comment in this other issue written by one the experts there: [configuring the `tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex` option.](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/7553#issuecomment-735915659)

---

*how I can find this option in my VSCODE?*

- You just have to first open your IDE on any file (it doesn't matter  the type of the file)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

  [image]

  and as you see it will open a list of shortcuts
- search for `"setting"` and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- you will see an interface with a search bar at the top.

   type `"TailwindCSS"`

   [image]
- in the list below scroll until you find an item with text `TailwindCSS > Experimental: Class Regex`.

  [image]
- now you can add your regex here inside the brackets following the instructions here [configuring the `tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex` option.](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/7553#issuecomment-735915659)

---

Here is the config created for you:

```js
"tailwindCSS.experimental.classRegex": [
   "classed\\(\"([^)]*)\"\\)"
]
```

as you see here, is an array of regexes.

---

result on the IDE:

[image]

Comment: **Tailwind Regex notes:**  provided regex works for double quotes, only.   For single quotes, you can add/replace the regex with `"classed\\('([^)]*)'\\)"`.   It also appears to not work once you add the bool value to `classed`.     Otherwise fantastic answer!

Comment: Holy crap, stellar answer.